# merge values in column in a row with the quotes separator "|", based on a comparison with the values of another column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

as the title suggests I'm trying to find a way to treat some data in a spreadsheet to google app. 
I think the best way is to directly set an example and thank you in advance for your support as always.

simply:

```
sheet1 (colA, colB)

sheet2 (colA', colB') 

sheet1        
  colA  colB     
1 xxx   40     
2 xxx   42     
3 yyy   42    
4 yyy   44 
. ...   etc. 


sheet2

colA'  colB'

1 xxx    40 | 42

2 yyy    42 | 44

3 ...    .. | ..  (etc.)
```

I would be grateful for a hint of code to google app script. 
thanks

Gì

EDIT (in progress)

hi,

I hope that by sharing the file answer your questions.

the sheet already exist, the code is written in part and I would need help on this.

there is no duplication in ColumnB for article xxx or yyy or zzz etc. ..

in sheet "sheet_demo" indicates that the script should be.

[Spreadsheeet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiuqXkUqDMgzdFM5aVNxeEhPbWFmbGhybl9TVkt4ZWc#gid=0)

---

```
function merge_col() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AiuqXkUqDMgzdFM5aVNxeEhPbWFmbGhybl9TVkt4ZWc");
  var ss_sorg = sheet.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var ss_dest = sheet.getSheetByName('sheet2');

  var sorg_data = ss_sorg.getRange("A2:C").getValues();
  var dest_data = ss_dest.getRange("A2:C").getValues();
  var dest_Cod = []; 
  var dest_Des = [];
  var temp_Cod, temp_Des;

  for (var i = 0; i < sorg_data.length; i++) {

    temp_Cod = null;
    temp_Des = null;

    for (var j = 1; j < sorg_data.length; j++) {

      if (sorg_data[i][0] == sorg_data[j][0].toString().match(sorg_data[i][0]) && sorg_data[i][0] != "") {

        temp_Cod = sorg_data[i][1];
        temp_Des = sorg_data[i][2];

        break;
      }
    }

    dest_Cod.push([temp_Cod]);
    dest_Cod.join('|');
    dest_Des.push([temp_Des]);
    dest_Des.join('|');
  }
  if (dest_Cod.length > 0 || dest_Des.lenght > 0) {
      ss_dest.getRange(2, 2, dest_Cod.length, 1).setValues(dest_Cod);  Logger.log(dest_Cod)
      ss_dest.getRange(2, 3, dest_Des.length, 1).setValues(dest_Des);  Logger.log(dest_Des)
  }
}
```

EDIT (FINAL)
TKS Serge!

```
function merge_col() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var header = data.shift();
  var col1 = data[1][0];
  var col2 = '';
  var col3 = '';
  var dataSheet2 = [header];
  for(var i=0 ; i<data.length ; i++){
    Logger.log(data[i][0]+'  -  '+col1+'  -  '+data[i][2])
    if(col1==data[i][0]){
      col1 = data[i][0];
      col2+=data[i][1]+' | ';
      col3+=data[i][2]+' | ';
    }else{
      dataSheet2.push([col1,col2,col3]); 
      var col1 = data[i][0];
      col2 = data[i][1]+' | ';
      col3 = data[i][2]+' | ';
    }
  }
  dataSheet2.push([col1,col2,col3]); 
  Logger.log(dataSheet2);
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet2');
  sheet2.clear();
  sheet2.getRange(1, 1, dataSheet2.length, dataSheet2[0].length).setValues(dataSheet2);
}
```

Comment: Just a few questions:  have you tried some code?  Are there more than 2 occurrence of the same item xxx or yyy?  Does sheet already exist?

Comment: Thanks, now it's perfectly clear :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code that does exactly what you expected using a simple loop and a comparison.

```
function merge_col() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var header = data.shift();
  var col1 = data[1][0];
  var col2 = '';
  var col3 = '';
  var dataSheet2 = [header];
  for(var i=0 ; i<data.length ; i++){
    Logger.log(data[i][0]+'  -  '+col1+'  -  '+data[i][2])
    if(col1==data[i][0]){
      col1 = data[i][0];
      col2+=data[i][1]+' | ';
      col3+=data[i][2]+' | ';
    }else{
      dataSheet2.push([col1,col2,col3]); 
      var col1 = data[i][0];
      col2 = data[i][1]+' | ';
      col3 = data[i][2]+' | ';
    }
  }
  dataSheet2.push([col1,col2,col3]); 
  Logger.log(dataSheet2);
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet2');
  sheet2.clear();
  sheet2.getRange(1, 1, dataSheet2.length, dataSheet2[0].length).setValues(dataSheet2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636164/counting-duplicate-cells-on-multiple-rows-and-columns-with-google-spreadsheet/21636998#21636998), he want to do almost the same. Modifying 2 lines of the code and it's done:

```
function myFunction() {
  var objList={};
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i in data){
    // for(var j in data[i]){
      if(typeof objList[data[i][0]]=="undefined"){
        objList[data[i][0]]=[]; // new array
        objList[data[i][0]].push(data[i][1]); // push the value of the second column
      }
      else{
        objList[data[i][0]].push(data[i][1]);
      }
    //}
  }
  var objTable=[];
  for(var k in objList){
   objTable.push([k,objList[k]]);
  }
  Logger.log(objTable);
  ss.clear();
  ss.getRange(1, 1, objTable.length, objTable[0].length).setValues(objTable);
}
```