# Finding a change in data using Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I am absolutely new to programming and Google scripts, but I am determined to learn and have some fun. I have figured out some basics, but have run into a dead end that I hope this community can help me get past.

I am trying to create a report builder that pulls data from a 3rd party and displays it in Google Sheets. The data is in and sorted, but now I want to insert a header row at each change in information (i.e. several items in the report happen on Mondays, so before the Monday section, I want to insert a header row that says "Monday").

I am confident I can get the header formatting right, but I cannot figure out the right code to detect the change in my data so that I can insert a blank row. Here is the section of code I am working with. For this purpose, the meetingday variable is simply an array of days of the week (i.e. [Sunday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Tuesday, Tuesday,...])

```
var meetingday = sheet.getRange(3,7,rowindex).getValues(); 
for (var i=0; i<meetingday.length; i++) {
 var j=[i + 1]
 if ([i]!=[j]) {Logger.log(meetingday[i])};
 }
```

I figured that if I could get the log to show the data changes I could then go to work to write the code that would insert a blank line at that point. Right now all I get is a list of the entire array.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael

UPDATED SCRIPT

```
var meetingdays = sheet.getRange(3,7,rowindex).getValues();
var meetingdayinitial = meetingdays[0];
   for (i=0; i<meetingdays.length;i++) {
 if (meetingdays[i]!=meetingdayinitial) {
   Logger.log("insert blank row here");
   var meetingdayinitial = meetingdays[i];
   }
 }
```

Comment: How is your data organized in the sheet ? does the weekday be alone in a cell ? please share an example sheet or show a screen capture (or explain more thoroughly)

Comment: @Sergeinsas Thanks for the reply. Here is a link to the first few rows of the report. The weekday information is in a cell by itself. I am trying to detect when the data in column G changes so that a header can be inserted. [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmE0JY2GXSRndEtlSTB3TUI4OWVpU3RYalg1ZHdNS3c&usp=sharing)

Comment: look at this post answer, the Loop I used is exactly what you need : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681523/merge-values-in-column-in-a-row-with-the-quotes-separator-based-on-a-comp/21698124#21698124  if you have diificulties feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am still stumped. Here is a link to my [full sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmE0JY2GXSRndGJwVzVFSF9KOG05MjBFYkRtcFlWLUE&usp=sharing). I updated my code to include a variable for the initial value of the array and use that to for comparison, but it continues to return too many blank lines. I updated my original post with the current code.

Comment: I'll have a look on this later... no time right now. Thx for clarification and sheet sharing

Comment: @Sergeinsas Thanks for the help! I spent more time with the post you linked to and figured it out. It was a beginner's mistake- I was not properly referencing the array in the meetingdays variable. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: So, case closed?   If so then please consider answering your post yourself for future users :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's a beginner's code, but it works for me. This bit of script is designed to find each time data in a specific column of a Google Spreadsheet changes. (i.e. you have a sheet of events sorted by day of the week and you want to know when the group of Monday events ends and Tuesday events begins). Earlier in my script I sort my events by day of the week and then this bit crawls through the list looking for each change; I have it save that point to an array that I can work with later; in this case I am adding a formatted header row at each change. Hope this helps!

```
 var meetingdays = sheet.getRange(3,7,rowindex).getValues();
 var meetingdaycompare = meetingdays[0][0];
 var rowarray = [[0]];
 var j = 1;
  for (i=0; i<meetingdays.length; i++) {
    if (meetingdays[i][0]!=meetingdaycompare) {
     rowarray [j] = [i];
     j++;
     meetingdaycompare = meetingdays[i][0];
     }
   }
```