# Google Apps Script - Unique with multiple columns

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm just going to draw my problem here :

```
      A          B          C
1 | Apple  | Macintosh | Red
2 | Banana | Dole      | Yellow
3 | Apple  | Cortland  | Green
4 | Banana | Del Monte | Green
```

I need a formula to return this :

```
      A               B                  C
1 | Apple  | Macintosh, Cortland | Red, Green
2 | Banana | Dole, Del Monte     | Yellow, Green
```

So basically, I need to get unique values for column A, while concatenating their respective attributes, I have no idea how to accomplish this, any hint?

Comment: look at that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681523/merge-values-in-column-in-a-row-with-the-quotes-separator-based-on-a-comp/21695056#21695056

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681523/merge-values-in-column-in-a-row-with-the-quotes-separator-based-on-a-comp/21698124#21698124) should put you on the right track, it does almost what you want: take every unique item from a column and concatenate other columns corresponding values.

Try to adapt it to your exact needs and don't hesitate to come back if you meet some issue on a particular point.